# Need to add div after each four div using jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to add `div` after each four `div's`. I have list of dynamically generated `div`. I want to add a `div` after each four `div's`. Below are the HTML

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row"> 
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
    </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Above div are dynamically generating through php script. For resolving the task i'm using jquery selector and `after()` function. Below is the script which i'm using for adding the `div` after four.

```
$(".addAfterThis:nth-child(4n)").after('<div class="clearfix"></div>');
```

But it adding wrongly, script is adding div after two `div's`.

I'm also adding [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/ymgdngxd/4/) Example that you can easily understand my problem. Can any one guide me where is the issue that i can fix it. I would like to appreciate. Thank you

Comment: the code is working you are wraping the tile and the image in separate addAfterThis tags

Comment: @madalinivascu code is adding the `div` after two but i want to add after four. Can you kindly check demo link

Comment: @Mr.Developer you code works just fine. Have a closer look at your html-.structure. It is added after the 4th element with the class `addAfterThis`.

Comment: So there are 2 possible solutions: change your html or use `:nth-child(8n)` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that :

```
$(".addAfterThis").each(function(index) {
   if ((index % 4) == 0 && index!= 0) {
      $(this).after('<div class="red">after 4th div</div>');
   }
})
```

Its works.

See http://jsfiddle.net/ymgdngxd/6/

Comment: Thanks let me check it.

Comment: Finally this changes working for me in your script `if (index!= 0 && (index % 2) == 1 ) ` and i removed the `addAfterThis` from first `div`. Thanks for share the knowledge...

Answer (score 1):

you want something like this..

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $.each($('.addAfterThis'), function(index, val) {

    if (index % 8 == 0) {
      if (index == 0) {
        //skip
      } else {
        $(this).after('<div class="red">after 4th div</div>');
        console.log(index)
      }
    }
  })
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: #ff0000;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center v-center bubble-contact addAfterThis">
  <div class="content">
    <h2 class="bubble-a center-block">D</h2>
    <h4>Dubai</h4>
    <p>This is paragraph</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 text-center hidden-sm hidden-xs bubble-img addAfterThis">
  <div class="row">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="http://tech21info.com/admin/wp-content/uploads/2013/03/chrome-logo-200x200.png" alt="">
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your code is working but there is some issue. I don't need after 8 i need after 4.  I change `if (index % 8 == 0) ` to `if (index % 4 == 0) `. After changes its adding after 5 div then 4.

Comment: Thanks for share the knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

tried so mush but can't done with nth-child(4n),

not under stand why,

but i solved it, just shared maybe it will helpfull for you.

see fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/ymgdngxd/7/

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $(".addAfterThis:nth-child(8n)").after('<div class="red">after 4th div</div>');
});
```